# Returning a array of structs

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to figure out how to modify my code to actually allow for me to create a array of structs in my readFile and then return the array to the main.

This is my data struct

```
struct data{

    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};
```

This is my current setup of my readFile function and then the call that I use currently for this function.

```
 struct data * readFile(){

    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen("hw3.data", "r");

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){

        count++;

    }

    if (feof(fp)){

        rewind(fp);

        struct data *vehicles = malloc((sizeof(struct data))* count);


        count = 0;
        char *token = NULL;
        while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){

            printf("%s", line);

            token = strtok(line,  " ");
            vehicles[count].model = token;

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].engineSize = atof(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].cost = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[count].color = token;

        }

    }


}
```

This is the main where I have my menu and where I will do my call for my readFile function.

```
int main(){

    int check = 1;
    int input;

    while (check == 1){

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below\n\n");

        printf("1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low\n");
        printf("2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high\n");
        printf("3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low\n");
        printf("4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n\n");

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to the above menu\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);

        //readFile()

        if(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4 || input == 5){

            if (input == 5){

                exit(0);

            }if (input == 1){

                //sort float high to low

            }if (input == 2){

                //sort float low to high

            }if (input == 3){

                //sort int value high to low

            }if (input == 4){

                //sort int value low to high

            }

        }else{

            printf("Enter a correct value for the menus above\n\n" );
        }

        readFile();

    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Almost. `line` is perpetually reused. It should be cleared to null (and the length arg zeroed) after each line is processed, thereby forcing a reallocation for the next line iteration. And note that each line ends up "belonging" to it's own record. Remember that, because someday someone has to free that data. Also, you could just use an expansion algorithm rather than the double file walk (the count of which isn't reflective of your record count correctly, btw).

Comment: It might be easier to use `fscanf`, eg. `fscanf(fp, "%s %f %d %s",...)` and allocate your struct with fixed size char arrays, eg. `char model[20],...` so you dont need to worry about extra allocation

Comment: The main reason i didn't use fscanf is because i couldn't quite figure out how it was supposed to be used because of the last argument that is needed for it, I believe the file buffer.

Comment: the last arguments are the addresses corresponding to the variables in the string, so for a "%d" you could pass `&vehicles[count].cost`

Comment: @JeffreyHennen the syntax is `fscanf(fp, format, arg1, arg2, ...);` where `fp` is the `FILE*` object, `format` is the format, `arg1`, `arg2` are pointers to the variables where to store the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct, the idea is OK but there are a few issues:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        count++;
}
```

That counts the number of bytes, I think based on the later code you want the
number of lines.

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    if(c == '\n')
        count++;
}
```

would give you the number of lines.

Down there

```
token = strtok(line,  " ");
vehicles[count].model = token;
...
token = strtok(NULL, " ");
vehicles[count].color = token;
```

is valid, but perhaps not what you want. `strtok` returns on success `line + some_offset` so if later you need to
add more characters to `vehicles[i].mode` or `vehicles[i].color`, you might
overwrite memory. `vehicles[i].color` is only at an offset of
`vehicles[i].model`. If you even want to reallocate, `realloc` will fail,
because you wouldn't be reallocation at the beginning of the requested memory
block. Also by doing this you will lose the beginning of the requested memory,
it will leak memory, because you cannot free it (`free(vehicles[i].color)` is
not valid)<sup>1</sup>.

Another problem is that only the initial line woul have the correct amount of
allocated memory and if you call `getline` with a non `NULL` pointer and
non-zero length, `getline` will reallocate memory if necessary and update the
pointer and the length. If the reallocation returns the same address, then your
previous values are going to be overwritten. If the reallocation returns a
different address, you previous pointer will become invalid.

I'd suggest (and I think it is the only safe way here) that you do a copy of token with `strdup` (if available, or `malloc`+`strcpy`)
and after that do:

```
while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){
    // the strtok calls
    ...
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    len = 0;
}
```

In this way your code won't leak memory and you would not overwrite memory.

**edit**

> *I should instead be setting the values of model and color with strcpy instead*

You can use `strcpy`, but you would need to allocate memory first, because
`model` and `color` are just pointers. The `malloc` call only reserved memory,
it does not initialize it. So just doing

```
strcpy(vehicles[count].model, token);
```

would be wrong, because it you would try to copy something on an undefined
location. That's what I mean with

> I'd suggest (and I think it is the only safe way here) that you do a **copy of token with `strdup` (if available, or `malloc`+`strcpy`)**

```
vehicles[count].model = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
if(vehicles[count].model == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // for example
    // free everything and return

    return NULL;
}

strcpy(vehicles[count].model, token);
```

The function `strdup` essentially does that: `malloc` + `strcpy`, so if your
system has `strdup` you could do it like this:

```
vehicles[count].model = strdup(token);
if(vehicles[count].model == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    // for example
    // free everything and return

    return NULL;
}
```

Another option would be to change your struct and instead of having pointers to
`char`, use `char` arrays:

```
struct data{
    char model[100];
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char color[100];
};
```

Now you can save strings with maximal length of 99 chars (which should be enough
for a model name and color) and just use `strncpy` instead, without the need of
extra memory allocation:

```
strncpy(vehicles[count].model, token, sizeof vehicles[count].model);
// making sure to terminate the string
vehicles[count].model[sizeof(vehicles[count].model) - 1] = 0;
```

> Also I just haven't had a chance to change the code for free (line) line =null and len =0

I don't know what you mean by that. Just add the lines after

```
vehicles[count].color = token;
```

before the end of the `while` loop.

> So then also I should be using the get line like I was in the second iteration through the file because I am currently over allocating?

The second loop is fine, the problem is that you are assigned the same (+
offsets) memory locations to different pointers and when `getline` reallocates
and gets a different address, the previous pointer becomes invalid. That's why

```
free(line);
line = NULL;
len = 0;
```

is important and you definitevly should do that.

To summerize: Your loop is fine, but you need to make these changes:

- make copies of `token` or change the struct to use `char` arrays
- add the

  ```
  free(line);
  line = NULL;
  len = 0;
  ```

  lines at the end of the loop and you'll be fine.

---

**fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>`vehicles[i].mode` would only point at the beginning of the memory
block if and only if the line doesn't start with an empty space. As you are
reading a file, you don't have any guarantee that this is true. And even if it's
true, I wouldn't count on that. Better doing the safe thing here and make a
copy. `free(vehicles[i].color)` is definitely wrong.

Comment: Note: If you're going to `free(line)` within the loop, be sure to NULL `line` after that, as well as zero-ing the counter. `getline` neither knows, nor cares, that the pointer you're giving it on successive iterations is dangling once that `free()` is invoked. Either that or simply don't `free` until *after* the loop. Each iteration will try and use the already allocated buffer. That dovetails nicely with the suggestion to use `strdup`. While not a standard lib function, the idea is still solid. It's POSIX, and that's good enough for most people.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're right, I missed setting `line = NULL`. I fixed my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Okay so in regards to the token situation, I should instead be setting the values of model and color with strcpy instead because I am currently setting the values of those equal to a pointer. Is that correct on that assumption? Also I just haven't had a chance to change the code for free (line) line =null and len =0

Comment: So then also I should be using the get line like I was in the second iteration through the file because I am currently over allocating?

Comment: @JeffreyHennen I made an edit addressing your last 2 comments.

Comment: Awesome,  thank you.  As far as the way I currently have count setup on that loop though I am actually allocating per byte read instead of per line correct? So I am actually over allocating by a large margin of my actual amount iv should be using.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen If you haven't updated the the first loop like I did in the answer, yes, you allocating to much memory. In fact you will try to read more lines than there are actually in the file, because your first loop calculates the number of total characters. Fix the loop like I did in the answer and you'll have the right amount of lines and allocations.

Comment: Yup,  I will do that for sure,  just trying to make sure I learn all this

Comment: I know that someone answered this earlier but they must have taken off the answer before. I was wanting to know in accordance with my original question on how to actually return and pass along the array that I created in the readFile() into the main. I want this so I can then pass it along to the other functions that I am going to be creating